# HTTP Methods: Why not always use PUT over POST?

Tags: http, protocols

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview):

> POST: Create a new resource (e.g. add a new article to a wiki, add a
>   new contact to a database).
>
> PUT: Update an existing resource (or create a new one if it doesn't
>   exist).

To me, it seems like PUT also encapsulates the functions of POST. So why not always use PUT? Or, perhaps there a scenario where POST is preferred?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PUT vs. POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)